# ipython 5.1 export interactive session to script

Tags: python, session, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

So, I know I can export an ipython session to a notebook, and then convert that notebook to many format using `jupyter nbconvert ...`.

However, the [doc](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=magic#magic-notebook) also says I should be able to export the session directly to a python script if I give the filename a `.py` extension. That doesn't work, it still generates a notebook json file.

Can I get the desired behavior in some way?

Thanks.

Comment: The doc in this case is wrong (it's fixed in [the dev version](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactive/magics.html?highlight=magic#magic-notebook)). You can use `%history -f foo.py` to save the current session to a Python file. [%history docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was, as Thomas K. said, use `%history -f ...` instead...

Comment: Wow I wish I'd known about this great command long ago!